# Double interpolation?

Tags: java, android, interpolation, animator

So, I've got a combination of `Keyframe`, `PropertyValuesHolder` and `ValueAnimator`. Both `Keyframe` and `ValueAnimator` have interpolators.

Code looks like:

```
Keyframe frame =
    Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, someValue);
frame.setInterpolator(interpolator1);

PropertyValuesHolder holder =
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("myProperty", frame);

ValueAnimator animator =
    ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(holder);
animator.setInterpolator(interpolator2);

animator.start();
```

The question is am I getting double interpolation or just a single one? What is the formula?

Comment: i believe that 5 minute debug session would answer your question if you add two breakpoints in those two interpolators

Comment: Ok, I'll dig some android sources

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through `ValueAnimator` and `KeyframeSet` sources. It seems that firstly fraction is interpolated in `ValueAnimator` and then also in `KeyframeSet`